# How does this condition work in this while-loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
while ((len = var1) != -1)
{

   // do something

}
```

Which is being compared to -1? `len` or `var1`?

This is Java EE.

Comment: did someone understand the problem?

Comment: @kakajan Yeah. He's asking what is being compared to -1, `len` or `var1`. Make more sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of an assignment `var = val` is the assigned value `val`. So what happens here is that `len` is assigned with the value of `var1`, and if (after the assignment) its value is not equal to `-1`, the loop is entered.

Answer (score 2):

The most technical answer, I suppose, would be that you are comparing `len` to -1, but that doesn't really capture what's going on.

What's really going on is that, for every check, you are setting `len` to `var1`, and then comparing `len`. So, if I'm not mistaken, even though the computer is actually comparing `len`, it will always have just been replaced with the value from `var1`, so the code will be functionally identical to

```
len = var1;
while(var1 != -1)
{ 
    len = var1;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is correct, however, your code is not quite correct. It would be closer to: `len = var1; while(var1 != -1) { len = var1; }`

Comment: @LaneSurface Good call. I forgot about that.